# jquery call not hitting the function in script.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, apache, function

I am trying to call a jquery function with nest json, AJAX and PHP and it does not seem to be hitting the function.  I click on the button and nothing happens.

I added an alert to the head of the function and I never get the alert either.

I have a couple of declarations in the script. These are in the head section.

```
         <script src="assets/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3-respond-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
         <script src="assets/js/vendor/jquery.3.2.1.js"></script>
         <script src="assets/js/main2.js"></script>
```

I have tried including the functions in the head section and that does not work.  Currently they are in the library at assets/js/main2.js.

I have tried multiple ways of calling the function including a button and anchor tags.  Currently this is the section of the code that is relevant.

```
                   <div class="contact_content">
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                       <div class="contact_message wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-duration="1.5s">
                                  <form action="#" id="formid">
                                     <div class="form-group"> <input class="form-control" name="name"
                        placeholder="Name" required="" type="text"> </div>
                            <div class="form-group"> <input class="form-control" name="email"
                        placeholder="Email" required="" type="email">             </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <div class="Descrizione">         
                                                         <label for="InserisciDescrizione" class=""><b>Message</b></label>
                                                                <textarea  class="form-control" id='message' placeholder="Type message:"
                                                     name='message'  rows='6' cols='50' value="" 
                                                            title="Message"></textarea>      
                                                 </div>
                                                     </div>
                             <a id="submit" href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</a>
                             </form> 
                       </div>
```

Here is the actual Jquery that is supposed to touch off the nested AJAX and PHP.

```
    $( '#submit').click(function jq1 () {

             alert("Handler for .click function called");

             doAjax();

             }

    )
```

It does not display the alert.  It also does not execute the code.  Am i supposed to set up a return to get the alert?  When I click the submit button nothing happens.

Is there anything I have to set up on the web server?  I am using Apache.

Comment: When your code doesn't work, simplify it until it does. If you don't know what's wrong, you're not quite at a point where we can be of much help.

Comment: First: At the top of main2.js, add `alert("main2");` - does that alert appear when you run? If not, check browser for 404 and change link.   Next, wrap your code inside document ready:  `$(function() { $("#submit").click(function() { alert("click"); }); });`    If you've defined your code in main2 and it's loaded in the head then the #submit element doesn't exist yet so doesn't get bound.

Comment: In the browser, enter just `$` - do you get `$ is undefined` or `ƒ (a,b){return new n.fn.init(a,b)}` - if the former then jquery is not loading.   Do you get any other errors in the browser console?

Comment: I changed the function call to be part of a button tag and added a simple function to the onclick and nothing happens.  It button depresses and unpresses and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the function call to an onclick in a button tag and nothing happens.  It presses and depresses but the alert never pops.

Here is the function

```
        <script language="javascript">
           function test() 

          { alert("Call"); }> </script>
```

and here it the button tag.

```
          <button type="button" id="btnEmail" onclick="test()" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

If I use a button tag it just presses.  If I use an anchor tag it doesn't reload the page, but, it jumps to the top of the page.

Am I simple.  This seems simple to me and it is not working.

Comment: Does anyone have any idea why a simple JavaScript function call would fail to execute?  It must be some type of conflict.  I have declared the latest Jquery library, is there something else I need to declare?

Comment: Fyi, I am running this in the browser and not the web server.